# Installing elasticsearch-transport-couchbase for elasticsearch 2.1 failes

Tags: installation, couchbase, elasticsearch-plugin

I used to install elasticsearch-transport-couchbase plugin very easy, however this time it didn't go well.

First I tried to install plugin using README as bellow:

```
bin/plugin -install transport-couchbase -url http://packages.couchbase.com.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/elastic-search-adapter/2.1.1/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-2.1.1.zip
```

It returns following error:

> ERROR: unknown command [-install]. Use [-h] option to list available commands

According to [es documentations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/installation.html):

> A plugin can also be downloaded directly from a custom location by specifying the URL:
>
> `sudo bin/plugin install [url]`

I tried this:

```
bin/plugin install http://packages.couchbase.com.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/elastic-search-adapter/2.1.1/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-2.1.1.zip
```

And the results was:

> Downloading
>   .........................................................................................................................DONE
>   Verifying
>   http://packages.couchbase.com.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/elastic-search-adapter/2.1.1/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-2.1.1.zip
>   checksums if available ... Failed: IOException[Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 403 for URL:
>   http://packages.couchbase.com.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/elastic-search-adapter/2.1.1/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-2.1.1.zip.sha1];
>   nested: IOException[Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:
>   http://packages.couchbase.com.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/elastic-search-adapter/2.1.1/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-2.1.1.zip.sha1];
>   NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find
>   .sha1 or .md5 file to verify) ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor
>   'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip

How can I install the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couchbase transport plugin v2.1.2 is not supporting Elasticsearch higher than 1.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

As [Reza notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119602/installing-elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-for-elasticsearch-2-1-failes/34127770#34127770), ElasticSearch versions > 2 require a newer plugin.

At the current time, that newer plugin would be version v2.2.1.2, but **don't rely on this** - instead, follow the installation guide on the couchbase git repository: [couchbase git repository elasticsearch plugin](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase). This is much more likely to have up to date information on both the process and correct plugin version.